# Required: Contacts App for iPhone 5c (IFTTT Compatible)

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, backup, contacts

I have iPhone 5c (iOS8). I recently added a recipe from IFTTT that lets me store any new contacts I add on my iPhone to a spreadsheet on my Google Drive account. I'm also using an app called "[Connect](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/connect-contact-manager-for/id659434552?mt=8)" that is a contacts manager and dialer app. It also lets me group my contacts and call with only a swipe.

My problem is that this connect app doesn't trigger the IFTTT Recipe, that's only triggered when I add a contact via the [default ios contacts app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdL21.png) (icon). I'm using connect-app by default, and so all contacts don't get updated to the spreadsheet when I add them.

Therefore, I'm posting this question to request for an ios app that could let me add contacts easily with grouping/speed-dialing, and also trigger the IFTTT recipe. The recipe only triggers when adding contacts via the default contacts app. I require these contacts as a backup, cause Google doesn't keep deleted contacts older than 1 month of deletion.

That's mostly all.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an app that syncs with the native iphone contacts...:

[FullContact](https://www.fullcontact.com/iphone/)

Answer (score 1):

The IFTTT recipe gets information from a specific source (channel) that is defined in the recipe. In this case I assume that you use a recipe which imports contacts to a spreadsheet on Google Drive and then it only imports contacts from the contacts application (the built-in one).

From what I am aware of there isn't any application currently that offers this synchronisation with Google Drive via IFTTT other than the iOS built-in one.

Comment: Is there any app that could let me add new contacts to a spreadsheet? Thanks!

Comment: @mk117 as you mentioned earlier the iOS built-in contacts app does that via IFTTT. Or do you mean a way to add contacts from Connect-app to a spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes! IFTTT allows that, although I require the contacts to be added from the Connect app to a spreadsheet... Would that be possible? Any app that could let me take a backup of contacts and-or call history automatically (Free app)